# converting activity into fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

This is a simple code to play a sound on click off a `button`, this code was initially written in Activity but now i want to change it to Fragments.

errors

1) The method `setContentView(int)` is undefined for the type Rajathmusic.

2) The method `create(Context, int)` in the type MediaPlayer is not applicable for the            arguments (Rajathmusic, int).

3)The method `findViewById(int)` is undefined for the type Rajathmusic.

I am just starting off with android development, any help would be appreciated!

```
public class Rajathmusic extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.v(TAG, "Initializing sounds...");

    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.rajath);

    Button play_button = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button3);

    play_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Playing sound...");
            mp.start();
        }
    });
    Log.v(TAG, "Sounds initialized.");
}}
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

1. `Fragment` has a method called `onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)`. Override it, inflate using the layout and return the view.
2. Since create method expects a `Context`, pass it using `getActivity()`
3. `findViewById(int)` can be called as `getView().findViewById(R.id.button3)`

Here is a sample code:

```
public class Rajathmusic extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Initializing sounds...");

        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.rajath);

        View v = getView();

        Button play_button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button3);

        play_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Playing sound...");
                mp.start();
            }
        });
        Log.v(TAG, "Sounds initialized.");
    }

}
```

Read more about `Fragment` lifecycle [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle) to know why I've put the code in `onActivityCreated` and not `onCreate`

Comment: super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); after this  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

Answer (score 2):

Use this code in overriden method `OnActivityCreated(...)` and instead of `this` use `getActivity()`, since new fragment is not activity any more.

Answer (score 2):

In fragment onCreate method is usually written as-

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState){
```

And Use-

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.rajath);
Button play_button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button3);
```

If you want to read more about fragments. [Check this link.](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

Copy the code from the `onCreate()` method from the activity and paste it into the `onCreateView()` method of the fragment.

To fix the errors, pass `getActivity` in place of this keyword and use `getView().findViewById()`.